# How to set data range based on radio button selected

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make the `min` and `max` variables change depending on the radio button checked. Currently my HTML looks like

```html
<input type="radio" name="type" class="frequency" value="0">
<label for="0">1960-2099</option>
<input type="radio" name="type" class="frequency" value="1">
<label for="1">Other range, e.g. 1970-2000</option>
```

And the js to generate the year range looks like

```js
$(".frequency").click(function(){
  var $msd = $("#startDate");
  var $month = $("#startMonth");
  var $year = $("#startYear");

  min = 1960
  max = 2099

  $('select').change(function () {
    var val = "01/" + $month.val() + "/" + $year.val();
      $msd.val(val);
  });

    select = document.getElementById('startYear');

    for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
       var opt = document.createElement('option');
       opt.value = i;
       opt.innerHTML = i;
       select.appendChild(opt);
    }

    var $mfd = $("#finalDate");
    var $monthf = $("#finalMonth");
    var $yearf = $("#finalYear");
    
  $('select').change(function () {
    var val = "01/" + $monthf.val() + "/" + $yearf.val();
      $mfd.val(val);
  });
  
    selectf = document.getElementById('finalYear');

    for (var i = min; i<=max; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        selectf.appendChild(opt);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `event` to the Event Listener, then:

```js
$(".frequency").click(function(event){
  var $msd = $("#startDate");
  var $month = $("#startMonth");
  var $year = $("#startYear");

  let min;
  let max;
  if (event.target.value === 0) {
    min = 1960
    max = 2099
  } else {
    min = 1970
    max = 2000
  }
```

I don't know Jquery, but it's pretty straightforward also in plain JS.

Comment: I should have said earlier, but I guess I should use some other thing that's not the value. Can I do the same as you did but with the ID instead of `e.target.value`?

Comment: Yea sure, you can put IDs on the HTML and check for `if (e.target.id === 'chosen-id') ...`. But I'd use the value with no problem since you already specified it.

Comment: When you say to add an "event" to the Event Listener, what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Nevermind, it seems like whatever I did worked just fine. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Glad you solved  I meant to pass a parameter event to the function in the Event Listener, so that you can use it later in the function.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make changes in min and max value depending on the radio button click then see if my solution works for you or not.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(".frequency").click(function() {
            let val = $(this).val();
            let min = 0;
            let max = 0;
            if (val == 0) {
                // 0 for 1960-2099
                // code goes here
                // assign value to min and max variable here
            }
            if (val == 1) {
                // 1 for Other range or whatever the range you want
                // code goes here
                // assign value to min and max variable here
            }

        });

    });
</script>
```